# How do I distinguish the users who do not exist now but exit previously?

Tags: twitter, tweepy

Now I have a user set involving one tweet. But some users do not exit now. I wonder how to distinguish those users from current users.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the only thing you can do in this case is to use the `users/lookup` or `users/show` endpoints to check whether those user IDs return a Not Found error (or similar) in order to filter them out from your result set.

Note that the [Twitter Developer Policy and Agreement](https://developer.twitter.com/en/developer-terms) explicitly states that if content has been removed from Twitter (if e.g. a user is deleted or suspended) you cannot display that it in app, or store that data, and must take steps to remove it from your system as soon as possible.